# Compile ffmpeg for armv7s

Tags: ios, macos, ffmpeg, armv7

I am trying to compile ffmpeg on OSX 10.9. I want to use the ffmpeg framework in an iOS testapplication using xCode.

I want to link the libfaac to ffmpeg and compile it for armv7s. When I follow the compilation guide (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) on the ffmpeg site, it does not work.

I used the following configuration:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --arch=armv7s
```

Another configuration I tried is

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --arch=armv7s --enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin
```

The difference between both configuration is the cross compile and target os.

Both configuration produces the following error message:

```
GNU assembler not found, install gas-preprocessor
```

Although, I have copied gas-preprocessor.pl into the directories /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin and modified the file read-write props by using chmod +x gas-preprocessor.pl

Can somebody help me to configure ffmpeg by giving for example an example configuration which does work?

Comment: do you need yasm installed perhaps?